# syntax in if statement is correct but code stops running after that(figured through printing)

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse

I get my problem in if statement in forward cargo function, I will also paste the question, I am using eclipse
forward_cargo():
Validate from_customer.customer_id, recipient_customer.customer_id, distance and weight of the freight
If valid,
auto-generate freight_id starting from 200 and initialize it. freight_id should be even
calculate freight_charge based on weight (Rs.150/kg) and distance (Rs.60/km)
Else, set freight_charge to 0

```
     #USM2-Assgn-5
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,customer_id,customer_name,address):
        self.__customer_id=customer_id
        self.__customer_name=customer_name
        self.__adress=address
    def validate_customer_id(self):
        cusID=str(self.__customer_id)
        if cusID[0]=="1" and len(cusID)==6: return True
        else: return False
    def get_customer_id(self):
        return self.__customer_id

    def get_customer_name(self):
        return self.__customer_name
    def get_address(self):
        return self.__address
class Freight:
    counter=198
    def __init__(self,recipient_customer, from_customer, weight, distance):
        self.__recipient_customer=recipient_customer
        self.__from_customer=from_customer
        self.__weight=weight
        self.__distance=distance
        self.__freight_charge=None
        self.__freight_id=None

    def get_recipient_customer(self):
        return self.__recipient_customer
    def get_from_customer(self):
        return self.__from_customer
    def get_weight(self):
        return self.__weight
    def get_distance(self):
        return self.__distance
    def get_freight_charge(self):
        return self.__freight_charge
    def get_freight_id(self):
        return self.__freight_id

    def validate_weight(self):
        if self.__weight%5==0: return True
        else: return False
    def validate_distance(self):
        if self.__distance>=500 and self.__distance<=5000: return True
        else: return False
    def forward_cargo(self):
        print(self.get_from_customer().validate_customer_id())
        if  self.get_from_customer().validate_customer_id()== True and self.get_recipient_customer().validate_customer_id()== True and self.validate_distance()==True and self.validate_weight()==True:
            print(self.get_from_customer().validate_customer_id())

            print(self.get_recipient_customer().validate_customer_id())
            self.__freight_charge=(self.__distance*60)+(self.__weight*150)
            Freight.counter+=2
            print(Freight.counter)
            self.__freight_id=Freight.counter
            print("hi")

        else: self.__freight_charge=0

kreta= Customer(123456,"nl","1230 jamaica")
bikreta= Customer(287397,"sad","1230 jamaica")
print(kreta.get_customer_id())
print(bikreta.get_customer_id())

ataki=Freight(bikreta,kreta,30, 500)
print(ataki.get_from_customer().get_customer_id(), ataki.get_recipient_customer().get_customer_id(),ataki.get_distance(), ataki.get_weight())
ataki.forward_cargo()
print(ataki.get_freight_id())   
print( ataki.get_freight_charge())
```

Comment: I think you're going to describe your problem better. This is pretty vague to me.

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't use setters and getters in Python. There's no good reason for that, and it makes your code much harder to read.

Comment: well the question wantedd me to use setters and getters, but if anyone can point out what else they want to know about the question that would be great because I have posted the actual question with code